# Gradle with JDK 9 Can't Build

Tags: gradle, java, java-9

I'm running a build using Gradle with open JDK 9.

The `gradlew shadow` command fails with the exception:

`java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.reflect.SourcepathIgnoringInvocationHandler cannot access class com.sun.tools.javac.file.BaseFileManager (in module jdk.compiler) because module jdk.compiler does not export com.sun.tools.javac.file to unnamed module @1c5af20`

But I am running the java command with the option to export this module to all unnamed modules. My full java command:

`exec /docker-java-home/bin/java --add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file=ALL-UNNAMED -Dorg.gradle.appname=gradlew -classpath /test/IotDevice/Applications/AppInsightsDocker/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain --stacktrace shadow`

Why am I still getting this exception?

Comment: If you check the bash file, those options are appended right after eachother to send to the `java` command: 
`eval set -- $DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS $JAVA_OPTS $GRADLE_OPTS`

Comment: What version of Gradle are you using?

Comment: Gradle 4.2 and here is some text so stack overflow will let me add this comment